# Easiest way to grep IPv6 / shortest regex that matches IPv6 (invalid address not a big deal)

Tags: regex, grep

I want to grep IPv6 addresess from log files that only contain valid IPv6 addresses that someone connected from (and also contains lines with IPv4 and many other lines without any IP, eg. /var/log/secure).

Therefore it's not so important for this regex to match only true RFC valid IPv6 such as massive regexes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses do, but it should match everything that somewhat resembles IPv6 so that it doesn't provide too many false positives and should be as short as possible, so that it's easy to remember and type this.

Comment: [This answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355379/372239) is really simple.

Comment: @Toto doesn't work, it matches timestamps too, so basically every line is matched

Comment: True but you can replace the `+` with a more correct length, like: `([0-9a-f]{1,4}:+){3,7}[0-9a-f]{1,4}`

Answer (score 0):

For a fast answer I would say:

```
egrep "(::)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}(::?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}(::)?"
```

but you have to assume that address contains at least two 'sections', e.g.:
`ff00:3456::` or `ff00::3456`, this: `ff00::` will not be matched.

Other solution I found is this regexp:

```
^(\:\:)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}(\:\:?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){0,7}(\:\:)?$
```

but, this will catch false-positives such as 'aaaa', 'abc' strings, so there must by an additional validation such as:

```
`^.*\:.*\:.*$`
```

In this case bash script snippet looks like this:

```
if [[ "$col" =~ ^(\:\:)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}(\:\:?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){0,7}(\:\:)?$ ]] && \
   [[ "$col" =~ ^.*\:.*\:.*$ ]] ; then
    echo "IPv6 match"
else
    echo "No match"
fi
```

this is to validate if `$col` represents IPv6 or not. Here you would need to develop a code to break log entry to sections first.